# React-Native Twitter login for Android

Tags: android, react-native, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric, twitter-login

Im trying to login via twitter with react-native. And obviously for iOS it works because Im using the react-native-simple-auth package.

But what about android? It doesn't appear that there's a package yet for native login for twitter?

Comment: recently i found a lib for twitter login using fabric https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I have found some useful packages for implement twitter login in react-native for both ios and android. These are the listed packages

> https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin
>
> https://github.com/Luzgan/react-native-twitter-signin
>
> https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric